# MAUI: the foreground service works in Android 8.1 but not in Android 13

Tags: c#, maui, foreground-service

I have a foreground service that it works in an emulator with Android 8.1, but when I try the same application in an Android 13 emulaltor, it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;



//Tiene que pertenecer al namespace raíz para poder tener acceso a Android.Content y otros
//recursos.
namespace GTS.CMMS.RegistroHorario.UI.Maui;



[Service]
public class AlarmasForegroundService : Service, IAlarmasForegroundService, IDisposable
{
    #region variables de clase
    //Class with PeriodicTimer() to check conditions periodically.
    private IServicioAlarmas _servicioAlarmas;

    private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000";
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "notification";
    private NotificationManager _notificationManager;
    #endregion variables de clase



    #region constructores
    public AlarmasForegroundService()
    {
        _servicioAlarmas = new ServicioAlarmas(new LocalizadorHelper());
        _servicioAlarmas.NotificacionNecesariaEvent += OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler;
    }
    #endregion constructores



    #region creación del foreground
    private void StartForegroundService()
    {
        _notificationManager = (GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager)!;

        createNotificationChannel(_notificationManager);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetAutoCancel(false)
            .SetOngoing(false)
            .Build();
        StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }


    private NotificationChannel? createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationMnaManager)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O) return null;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationMnaManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

        return channel;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }


    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        StartForegroundService();
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }
    #endregion creación del foregroud



    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        _servicioAlarmas.Iniciar();
    }



    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        _servicioAlarmas.NotificacionNecesariaEvent -= OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler;

        _servicioAlarmas.DetenerAsync();
        base.OnDestroy();
    }



    #region implementación del intefaz IAlarmasForegroundService
    public void Iniciar()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmasForegroundService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }



    public void Detener()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmasForegroundService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StopService(intent);
    }
    #endregion implementación del intefaz IAlarmasForegroundService




    #region manejadores de eventos
    private void OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler(string paramStrMensajeAlarma)
    {
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentTitle("Servicio trabajando (Título)")
            .SetContentText(paramStrMensajeAlarma)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .SetAutoCancel(false)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .Build();


        _notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
    #endregion manejadores de eventos
}
```

Is it needed some special configuration for Android 13?

Thanks

Comment: I remember, on Java I had to modify the services with some flag mutable, some time ago, because of the newer versions of Android. I am not sure if it concerns .NET or not.

Comment: Android 12 introduced some changes to how services work, and both Xamarin and Maui apps need to support the new ways: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#:~:text=Performance-,Foreground%20service%20launch%20restrictions,for%20the%20few%20special%20cases).